# Options -Indexes Code in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I just wanted to add a simple index.html to www re-direct command in an .htaccess file
When I opened the existing .htaccess file, the 'Options -Indexes' command was already in there.  What exactly is this command? What is it instructing the search engines etc. to do?
Not a programmer, just an SEO manager.  Thanks much, MB

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered with a single link to the documentation.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options It ensures that a request to `/directory` won't display a list of directory contents absent an index.html

Comment: And http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: Basically: `Options +Indexes` makes it easier for baddies to find exploitable/sensitive files, which is why it is `Options -Indexes` to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

The Indexes option sets whether you can "browse" the directory or not. If indexes is set to plus, and the directory has no index.html or index.php (of whatever) file, it will show the contents of the directory just like your filemanager would do. So if there are ten images in there, it simply shows them as a list with links to the actual image. You can click them and open them.